# Is there a jQuery TextboxList?

Tags: jquery, facebook, mootools, textboxlist

Facebook have a great TextboxList component.
[alt text http://img10.imageshack.us/img10/1803/textboxlistfacebook.png](http://img10.imageshack.us/img10/1803/textboxlistfacebook.png)

This has [just been ported (from scratch) into MooTools](http://devthought.com/blog/projects-news/2009/04/the-new-textboxlist-is-here/).

Does anyone know if this exists in jQuery?

edit: ahh! *autocomplete* was the keyword i was missing. cheers!

Comment: Google could be a great idea!

Comment: Agreed - if u get the correct keywords. (sigh)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[A quick google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+facebook+autocomplete) revealed the following:

- [jquery facebook autocomplete](http://wharsojo.wordpress.com/2008/02/18/jquery-facebook-autocomplete/)
- [FCBKcomplete v 2.01](http://www.emposha.com/javascript/fcbkcomplete.html)
- [Facelift](http://journal.suteki.nu/2008/11/11/facelist-improved-facebook-autocompletion-jquery-plugin/)

Comment: Thanks for the link to Facelift!  I've found the other two in every search I've performed, but they didn't fit my needs.  Facelift adds the features they were missing.

Answer (score 3):

devthought have also ported it to JQuery

- [TextboxList](http://devthought.com/projects/jquery/textboxlist/)

Comment: When it's down you can find TextoxList for jQuery here as well - [textboxLink](http://www.binpress.com/app/textboxlist-for-jquery/77)